# I want to sum all values in a column

Tags: c#, datagridview, sum

I want to sum a column of values in my `DataGridView`.

I found many questions online about that, but they all require a `DataTable` which I don't have.

So I made a for cycle, but it only sums the last two values of the column,
can you figure out what's wrong with it?

```
private void Sum()
{
    Double sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i + 1 < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        sum = (Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString())
                + Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i + 1].Cells[3].Value.ToString()));
     }

         lblTotal.Text = sum.ToString();

}
```

Comment: Because you always re-assign `sum` for your `i` and  `i+1` rows. At the end, your `i` and `i+1` will be your last 2 rows, that's why it returns sum of these 2 row values. Instead of that, just start `i` from `0` to less than `dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1` and use `sum += ...` in your loop.

Comment: You assign a new sum value every cycle in the loop so it will only show the last sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't quite correct; try using the [`+=`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx) operator to sum the values and a minor adjustment to the upper limit for the `for` loop...

```
private void Sum()
{
    Double sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        sum += Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString());
    }

    lblTotal.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```

Comment: It was so easy, I'm just a little tired, it works now

Answer (score 1):

use `+=` operator:

```
 sum += Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private void Sum()
{
    Double sum = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i + 1 < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        sum += (Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString())
                + Double.Parse(dataGridView1.Rows[i + 1].Cells[3].Value.ToString()));
     }

         lblTotal.Text = sum.ToString();

}
```